# Trying to make a calculator but code is not working

Tags: python

The calculator works by the following algorithm:
you add your calculation with a space in between numbers and operations and it prints out the result.
When I enter this code python is saying that `calset[1]` index is out of range which makes no sense.
What do I do?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"D:/pycharm projects/helloworld/calc 2.py"`, line 5, in <module>
    while 

    calset[1] != '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/':
    IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Code:

```py
cal = input("Calculation Required: ")
calset = cal.split(' ')
y = 0
while calset[1] != '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/':

    if '**' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "**"):
                x = calset.index("**")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) ** float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '/' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "/"):
                x = calset.index("/")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) / float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '*' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "*"):
                x = calset.index("*")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) * float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '+' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "+"):
                x = calset.index("+")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) + float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '-' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "-"):
                x = calset.index("-")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) - float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    else:
        calset.clear()
        cal = input("Calculation Required: ")
        calset = cal.split(' ')
print(calset[0])
```

Comment: IndexErrors mean that you're trying to access an element that doesn't exist in a sequence

Comment: `calset[1] != '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/'` this doesn't do what you think it does. you need to put the operators in a sequence and use `in`

Comment: If I input "5+5", what do you think `cal.split(' ')` would evaluate to?

Comment: what do you mean? can you please elaborate.

Comment: if you input 5 + 5

Comment: with a space in between

Comment: right, but what if I didn't include a space? then `calset` would be a list with a single element, and python indexing starts at 0

Comment: yes but i am adding spaces

Comment: still its not running

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are. or, maybe you've removed all but one of the elements of `calset`? and then `calset[1]` (the second element in the list)  doesn't exist anymore

Comment: try running the code

Comment: not in a place to do that

Comment: so your list only has one element if trying to access the second element raises an IndexError

Comment: it has 3 elements

Comment: i am printing the list and it has 3 elements

Comment: print it with every iteration of your loop

Comment: i am doing that

Comment: well, you delete three elements from the list with every operation, so at that point, you'd have zero elements in your list, and then your `while` condition is reevaluated

Comment: but the loop doesn't even start running because even in the first iteration it does not think that the list has more than 1 element even though the print function shows that it has more than one element.

Comment: when you have time please try running the code.

Comment: I think the loop does start running, but like i said, your condition (`calset[1] == '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/'`) doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: also, you should never modify a sequence while you loop through it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise version that works pretty well.  It doesn't handle operator precedence and it assumes that the input is formatted just right, but it will calculate the value of an equation of the form "v1 [<op> v2]...":

```
cal = input("Calculation Required: ")
calset = cal.split(' ')

ops = {
    '**': lambda v1, v2: v1 ** v2,
    '+': lambda v1, v2: v1 + v2,
    '-': lambda v1, v2: v1 - v2,
    '*': lambda v1, v2: v1 * v2,
    '/': lambda v1, v2: v1 / v2,
}

while len(calset) > 2:

    v1 = float(calset[0])
    op = calset[1]
    v2 = float(calset[2])

    if op not in ops:
        raise Exception("Bad Op: " + op)

    calset[0:3] = [ops[op](v1, v2)]

print(calset[0])
```

Sample run:

```
Calculation Required: 2 ** 3 + 2 * 5
50.0
```

Comment: While this fixes the OP's issue with the programming, the OP should note that their scheme doesn't properly account for the correct order of mathematical operations.

Comment: Yeah...I said that at the top of my answer - I think there must be a library that evaluates arbitrary expressions like this, but with the right precedence, and with parens handled and such.  Otherwise, to do it right and really have some fun, one should write a basic calculator lexer/parser/evaluator.  Any programmer should go through that exercise at least once.

Comment: Totally -- I just want to be sure the OP sees it

Comment: @Paul H is there any way to write a function that takes the input without spaces in between and converts it into a list and also accounts for any user error like adding extra spaces by mistake or any other input error possible.

Comment: @user14331794 yes there. it likely involves so-called "regular expressions" or a very ambitious set of `.split(<operator>)` method calls on your string

Comment: @user14331794 - the right thing to do is to define a lexer and parser that describe the "language" you're looking to implement.  Math expressions are a simple "language".  The calculator example is the classic "hello world" of parser building.  Luckily, I found one [HERE](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html) that is exactly this in a single Python file.  If you can study and understand what this file is doing, you'll understand the basics of writing a parser, which is how you normally attack any problem like this once it gets beyond a few simple string splitting tricks.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have said "THE right thing to do" above.  There are likely other appropriate ways to attack this sort of problem.  But defining a lexer and a parser is a classic way of solving this sort of problem.  It's a great thing to know how to do if you want to be a valuable programmer. - The classic tools to do this are [Lex & Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/).  These two tools are the grandfathers of many newer tools for building parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of case not covered like if user enter two space, or two operator sign you need to write all logic check that might happen.
where as i had made few change so that you can get output and build more advance cal.
In your sol you delete the list after delete the list have index 1
because you delete +,/ etc from list and assign new list to result which have only one index 0, so it gives you error . try to use 'in'   (not== '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/')

here is updated code...

```
cal = input("Calculation Required: ")

calset = cal.split(' ')
print(calset)
y = 0
lng=len(calset)
index=1
while calset[index] == '**' or '*' or '+' or '-' or '/':

    if '**' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "**"):
                x = calset.index("**")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) ** float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '/' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "/"):
                x = calset.index("/")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) / float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '*' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "*"):
                x = calset.index("*")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) * float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '+' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "+"):
                x = calset.index("+")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) + float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    elif '-' in calset:

        for i in calset:
            if (i == "-"):
                x = calset.index("-")

                y = float(calset[x - 1]) - float(calset[x + 1])
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                del calset[x - 1]
                calset.insert(x - 1, y)

    else:
        calset.clear()
        cal = input("Calculation Required: ")
        calset = cal.split(' ')
    lng=len(calset)
    if lng == 1 :
          index=0
    print(calset)
    print(lng)
print(calset[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

i also made another calculator which is much easier

```
z = float(input('Number: '))

while True:
    operation = input('Operation: ')
    if operation == "clear":
        print(0)
        z = float(input('Number: '))

    elif operation == "p":
       n = float(input('Number: '))
       z = z + n
       print(z)

    elif operation == "m":
        n = float(input('Number: '))
        z = z * n
        print(z)

    elif operation == "d":
        n = float(input('Number: '))
        z = z / n
        print(z)

    elif operation == "s":
        n = float(input('Number: '))
        z = z - n
        print(z)

    elif operation == "e":
        n = float(input('Number: '))
        z = z ** n
        print(z)


    else:
        print('Error: Incorrect Operation')
        z = float(input('Number: '))
```

Comment: @Paul H is this calculator better.

Comment: this is much simpler and cleaner